# Changing position to float with jQuery not working?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I got a webpage which is composed of content and footer.
The main part of the content is a div which contains an iframe when I click on a button.
When this iframe appears, my content overlaps the footer so I tried to fix it by this way :

- start with footer like it :

  ```
  footer {
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     bottom: 0;
     position:fixed;
     width:100%;
     padding-bottom: -40px;
  }
  ```

then when my iframe appears, switch `position:fixed;` by `position:float` (which gives what I expected to when I make the change by my hands but ...
it looks like jQuery can't modify it ?

Here is my jQuery call :

```
$('footer').css("color", "red"); // it works
$('footer').css("position", "float"); // it doesn't work
```

Can't jQuery do it ? Am I missing something ?
Thanks

Comment: `position:float` is not a valid `value`

Comment: AFAIK, `float` isn't a valid property for the `position` rule in CSS. Did you mean something like `float: left;`? (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: `float:left` or `float:right` are only valid!

Comment: Actually, if I understand correctly what you want to do, you probably meant `position: static`, which is the default

Comment: if it works when you change the CSS rule by hand, probably what's happening is it's just ignoring the rule, which it doesn't understand, and defaulting back to `position: static`; I imagine that when you try to change it via JS, the DOM just rejects the change, since it doesn't recognize the value, and leaves the `position` rule unchanged.

Comment: @kenbellows Exactly what was happening, thanks a lot, since it was working I didn't remember that position:float doesn't exist and kept trying it. Works with static :)

Comment: @Xneyte then I'll add as an answer, if you wouldn't mind marking correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the page, it sounds like the `position` value you want is actually `static`, rather than `float`. There is a CSS rule called `float`, but it does something pretty different. Try this instead:

```
$('footer').css("position", "static"); // it *should* work
```

As to why it was working when you changed the CSS rule by hand, the thing to remember is that the browser ignores CSS rules with values it doesn't understand and acts as if they weren't there. What's probably happening in this case is the browser doesn't understand `position: float`, so it's just ignoring the rule and using the default. As it happens, the default value for `position` is `static`, which is what you want.

I imagine that when you tried to change the `position` rule via JS, the DOM again said "hey, I don't know what this rule means, so I'll pretend it doesn't exist". You might think this would overwrite or clear out the `position: fixed` rule, but it won't because of the "cascading" nature of CSS. Setting rules in JS on a DOM node is equivalent to setting inline rules, which doesn't affect rules in `<style>` blocks or external stylesheets. So in this case, CSS said "I don't know what this inline rule means, so I'll revert back to the `<style>` rule that I do understand."

An interesting experiment to try would be to set the `position: fixed` in JS at the start of the page instead of in a `<style>` block (or external sheet, not sure which you're using) and try the broken `position: fixed` code again. It might work again in this case because the `position: fixed` might be overwritten by the bad rule, which would have the same effect as using the faulty rule in your stylesheet, namely defaulting to `static`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that `position:float;` doesn't exists. Valid values for position are:

- static
- relative
- fixed
- absolute

<kbd>**[Relevant Source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)**</kbd>

You can however use the float property (for example `float: left`, which in jquery would be `$('footer').css("position", "float");`)

Comment: Hum well ok I'm so dumb, if it works when i change it manually, it is just because it works when it is empty. ><